# Error reading a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am very new PHP. Can some please solve my problem?

The following code works absolutely fine when i tried to execute using xampp in windows. But it dosen't work on Ubuntu when i try executing through ssh terminal.

Following is the php warning. but when i tried it on windows it works fine for all the records in CSV (it gives me insert or update statement for each record in the CSV)

> PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/myetexts/Documents/codes/Pearson/test2.php on line 8
>   PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/myetexts/Documents/codes/Pearson/test2.php on line 9

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);
    $file = fopen('NZ_Price_list.csv', 'r');
    $count = 0;
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db('newlocalabc');

    while(!feof($file)){
        $record = fgetcsv($file);
        if(!empty($record[0])){
           // echo 'ISBN: '.$record[0].'<br />';
        $price =round(($record[11])/0.85,2);
        if($record[3]== "Higher Education" || $record[3] == "Vocational Education"){
            $price =round((($record[11])/0.85)/0.97,2);
        }
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `isbn` = '.$record[0];
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $data = mysql_fetch_object($result);

            $nsql = "UPDATE `products` SET `price` = '".$price."', `cover` = 'pics/cover4/".$record[0].".jpg', `cover_big` = 'pics/cover4/".$record[0].".jpg' WHERE `products`.`isbn` = ".$record[0].";";
        }else{
            $nsql = "INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `isbn`, `title`, `publisher_id`, `description`, `supplier_id`, `price`, `author`, `cover`, `cover_big`, `status_id`, `timestamp`) 
            VALUES (NULL, '".$record[0]."', '".addslashes($record[1])."', '7','Not Available', '72', '".$price."', '".$record[2]."', 'pics/cover4/".$record[0].".jpg', 'pics/cover4/".$record[0].".jpg', '0',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        }
        echo $nsql.'<br />';
        //echo $price.'<br />';
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($record);exit;
        }
        unset($record);
        $count++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    ?>
```

Hoping to hear back from some one soon.

Comment: For whatever reason, the `fopen()` has failed: file doesn't exist? invalid permissions?

Comment: You might try specifying a full path to the file.  My guess is that file is not present in the same directory you are running the script from, or it is not readable  by the script (permissions issue)

Answer (score 2):

The call

```
   fopen('NZ_Price_list.csv', 'r');
```

fails. A failing call doesn't return a so called [PHP resource](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php), but a boolean. Possible reasons are these:

- File does not exist - file_exists()
- Application can't open file for reading - is_readable()

Please be more specific an e.g. use an absolute file path like this and do some sanity checks:

```
$filePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/..somePath../NZ_Price_list.csv';

// Ensure, that file exists and is reable
if ( ! file_exists( $filePath )) {
   throw new Exception( 'File does not exist: ' . $filePath , 10001 );
}
if ( ! is_readable( $filePath )) {
    throw new Exception( 'File not readable: ' . $filePath , 10002 );
}

// Then, try to open the file
$fileHandle = fopen( $filePath, 'r');

if ( ! is_resource( $fileHandle )) {
   throw new Exception( 'Failed to open file: ' . $filePath , 10003 );
}
```

Furtermore, PHP's [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) call might help. `stat()` provides details of a file - but can fail too...

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you please explain me the $filepath on the first line please. I am not sure how it works.

Comment: @user2636163 dirname( __FILE__ ) is the path of the currently running script. I propose to create an absolute file path.